# Storing values from specific function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-re

I extracted some specific names of text. The text and function are described below :

```
import re
text = '''
def cal_revenue(revenues_store, profit_margin, average_profit):
     average_profit = revenues_store * profit_margin 
     return average_profit
'''

# Extract names
lines = text.split('\n')
for line in lines:
  x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
  if x != None:
      values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
      function_name = values[0]
      arguments = values[1][:-2].split(', ')

      print(f"Function Name: {function_name}")
      print(f"Arguments: {arguments}")
```

This function works well and gives the expected results. Now I want to store all of these results in separate dictionaries

```
    # Create dictionaries
    splited_table1= dict() 
    splited_table2= dict() 
        
    # Extract names
    def extraction_variables(text):
      lines = text.split('\n')
      for line in lines:
        x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
        if x != None:
            values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
            splited_table1 = values[0]
            splited_table2 = values[1][:-2].split(', ')
            return splited_table1, splited_table2


extraction_variables(text)
    
    splited_table1
    splited_table2
```

But after execution of this command dictionaries are empty. So can anybody help me how to store values in dictionaries from the function above?

Comment: Dicts need keys. What keys do you expect to see there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
text = '''
def cal_revenue(revenues_store, profit_margin, average_profit):
     average_profit = revenues_store * profit_margin 
     return average_profit
'''
splited_table1 = {}
splited_table2 = {}
# Extract names

def extraction_variables(text):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
      x = re.search(r"^def.*:$", line)
      if x is not None:
          values = x[0].split('def ')[1].split('(')
          # function_name = values[0]
          # arguments = values[1][:-2].split(', ')

          splited_table1 = values[0]
          splited_table2 = values[1][:-2].split(', ')


          return splited_table1, splited_table2

e = extraction_variables(text)
print(e)
```

Not much modified but working for me.
if not working, you need to show the output of your code

Comment: I tried, but the dictionaries are still empty. I need to have text inside…

Comment: Why are you using dictionaries to store simple values?
```